# Android Play Games Services Leaderboard doesn´t work in release apk

Tags: android, apk, google-play-games

I made a simple game and use the google play games services.

When I debug my game on my devices, everything works fine (Leaderboard and Achievements), but when I use a signed APK, only the achievements works.

The leaderboard does not get any score. I tested it on two different devices and with different accounts.

I checked the certificate fingerprint and created a new leaderboard. Did not help.

I get this in logcat, after starting my app:

```
09-11 13:44:47.182 26465-4990/? E/PopupManager: No content view usable to display popups. Popups will not be displayed in response to this client's calls. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
09-11 13:44:47.236 26465-4990/? E/PopupManager: No content view usable to display popups. Popups will not be displayed in response to this client's calls. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
09-11 13:44:47.456 26465-28247/? E/Volley: [56006] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/played
09-11 13:44:47.859 26465-28244/? E/Volley: [56003] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/scores?language=de_DE
```

I call `if (client != null && client.isConnected()) -> Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(client, "xxxxx-xxxxx", getHichScore());` at my `onConnected()` in my mainActivity.

Comment: Please share error logs from device as well

Comment: Something like this? I edit my Question

Comment: looks like access error? are you getting any Access Not Configured. error? make sure your signature of prod is correct not using debug keystore

Comment: No, there was everything okay. I think it is working now. I made a new game in game services console and changed the ressorces in my app. Then I had to reinstall the play games app on my device, because it was trying to open the new leaderboard with the old app id.